# Send Emails using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have a Contact form and i want to send an email to the email of emailField.

```
$subject = $_POST['demail2'];
$message = $_POST['textarea'];
$mail_from = $_POST['demail'];
$name = $_POST['dname'];
$header = "from: $name";
$to = "some-email@some-provider.com";

$send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

if ($send_contact)
{
    echo "We´ve recieved your information";
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

I try this but not work...

Comment: 1. What you mean by saying "not work"? 2. DO you have your server configured to send emails?

Comment: So you get _"Error"_ on your screen?

Comment: check if php.ini is correctly configured

Comment: I dont have errors, but i dont receive the email. i have to have a server? how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$subject = $_POST['demail2'];
$message = $_POST['textarea'];
$mail_from = $_POST['demail'];
$name = $_POST['dname'];

$to = "some-email@some-provider.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

$headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <'.$mail_from.'>' . "\r\n";    
$send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open your `php.ini`
2 - Find and uncomment `sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i"`
3 - Restart `apache`.

**NOTE:**
You should place the **FULL PATH** (i.e.  `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` )
`sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"`

If is still fails, you should enable and display errors in order to debug properly, for that, add the following code at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use error_get_last(), when mail() returns false.

With print_r(error_get_last()) you get proper error